# Docker networking on VMware VM

Tags: docker, networking, vmware

I need to run 4 containers on a VM hosted on VMware Esxi. I need 3 containers to be on one network and the other remaining container on a separate network. The 3 containers need to talk to certain applications in the organisation and hence should go out via a VLAN/port group attached to the VM in VMware. The other container needs to be on a separate VLAN as it talks to a different group of applications in the organisations.

The host VM is running Ubuntu 20.4.
I have attached 2 NICs on the VMS (both different VLANS)
I am now trying to setup 2 static routes as the VMs need to have 2 gateways to route traffic and this is not working very well.

Is there a different approach I should be using to make this more simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using macvlan on docker ? You could choose the parent interface.

You can create and assign a network for each group of containers with a different parent interface.

docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=172.16.86.0/24 --gateway=172.16.86.1 -o parent=eth0 net
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=172.20.0.0/24 --gateway=172.20.0.1 -o parent=eth1 net_2

More informations : https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/